# Javascript code as a variable

Tags: javascript, code-reuse

Ok, this may sound a bit crazy but hear me out :)

I would like to do the following in javascript:

```
define START_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION = "try {"
define END_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION   = "} catch () {}"

function TEST () {
    START_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION
    // rest of function
    END_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION
}
```

Basically, can I define a list of javascript lines (code) and include them as above?  I'm looking for a technique versus comments about whether this is a good idea or not or debate over wrapping all functions in a try/catch block.

I know about eval(), but I dont think you can eval statements like the above.

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do, which is to use pre-written snippets to build new functions, while I'm not sure this is a great approach, I think the best way to accomplish this is to use a server-side language as a sort of "compiler", where you have a small templating language that you use in javascript, just something like {{snippet1}} and then use a server-side language that will go through and replace every instance of {{snippet1}}, for example, with the corresponding code snippet, then you can re-run it anytime anything changes and you have your jscript files updated

Answer (score 4):

This might be goofy but you could define a master function and run other functions through it by passing them in.

```
var execute = function(func){
    alert('before');
    func();
    alert('after');
};

function sayHi(){
    alert('hi there');
}

execute(sayHi);
```

As requested, an example with passing arguments.

```
var execute = function(func){
    alert('before');
    var ret = func.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    alert('after');
};

function saySomething(sayWhat){
    alert(sayWhat);
}

execute(saySomething,'hey there');
```

Comment: This might be more like the "Javascript way".

Comment: Can you provide an example that passes arguments to the function?

Comment: @Asaph: Consider the arguments array that is part of a called function  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments

Answer (score 1):

That is not allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, clearly - but is there a technique that can achieve that goal?

Comment: As far as I know, no. It looks like you are trying to simulate a macro, and I believe macros are used with complier languages, not  interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the Function prototype:

```
Function.prototype.tryThis = function() {
    try {
        this();
    }catch(ex){
        alert('Caught '+ex);
    };
};

function tryIt() {
    alert('Inside tryIt');throw "My Error from tryIt";
}

tryIt.tryThis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into aspect oriented programming for JavaScript. You can create hooks for function entry and exit. Tools like JSUnit do this for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the "new Function" operator. I've never used it myself, since I'm not clinically insane, but I believe you can pass it a string which it will `eval`uate and use as the function body. You can also get the code for each function by calling `myFunction.toString()`. So put together, it'd be something like this:

```
var functionsToMessUp = ['myFunc1', 'myFunc2'];

for (var i = 0; i < functionsToMessUp.length; ++i) {
    var theFunc = window[functionsToMessUp[i]]; // assuming they're in global scope
    window[functionsToMessUp[i]] = new Function(
        START_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION
        + theFunc.toString()
        + END_OF_EVERY_FUNCTION
    );
}
```

Now, the above almost certainly won't work - there's parameters and other things to take into consideration, and I don't even think that's how the new Function constructor works, but if you really want to go down this path (which I really don't recommend), then this might be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    callback();
  } catch() {}
}

var myFunction = function() {
  // do some stuff
};

tryCatch(myFunction);
```